# Decision rule matching for future predictions in R

Tags: r, random-forest, rules, rule-engine

I have a set of decision rules extracted from RF using inTrees package. For future work I want to use the test data to predict the value resulted by rules. My question is how can I check the rule condition for each element of an observation?

```
Observations:(908*7)
x[,1]               X[,2]  X[,3]   X[,4]  X[,5]  X[,6]  X[,7] TARGET
SUPPORTING DEVICES  10     120      144   553     6     3.85  72.02
OPHTHALMOSCOPE      10     133.81   143   345     7     7.5   191.94
OPHTHALMOSCOPE      10     167.22   280   345     2      1     13.99


Rules & prediction: (428:2)

X[,1] %in% c('MICROSCOPE','OSCILLOSCOPE') & X[,5]>4428.534912 &    
X[,5]<=4747.5 & X[,6]<=35.5  pred=3555.085
X[,1] %in% c('COLPOSCOPES','ENDOSCOPE','STROBOSCOPE') &    
X[,4]<=159.885038579262 & X[,4]>149.693058265924 & X[,4]<=152.534780178906  
& X[,6]<=35.5 & X[,7]<=2.85 pred=23856.56
X[,1] %in% c('COLPOSCOPES','ENDOSCOPE','STROBOSCOPE') & X[,2]<=3.5 &    
X[,4]>159.885038579262 & X[,4]>210.163123531761 & X[,6]<=35.5   pred=22.845
```

I want to compare each observation with each rule and get the aggregated prediction value for each rule satisfied by that observation. Ultimately to be used as rule engine

Please help! Thanks.

I have used this:

```
Y<- TRCx
  for (i in c(1:nrow(Y)))
    {
      X<- Y[1,]
      for(j in c(1:nrow(rules)))
          {

        if (rules$condition [j]){

         p <- mean(rules$pred[j]) 
        }
        else{
          0
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

given a test data set "X" (if it is another name rename it to "X"), and a rule condition, say

```
cond = "X[,1] %in% c('MICROSCOPE') & X[,5]>4428"
```

then we can use the following to get the indices of data points that satisfy the condition:

```
cond <- paste("which(", cond, ")")
ind <- eval(parse(text=cond))
```

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you @H.D it works fine. But I am looking for opposite scenario. I want to know which rule(s) is followed by 1st observation in X and same for all 908 observations. And if rule is followed, it should result in related predicted value.

Comment: @NilanjanJoshi how about the following function that returns an activation relationship between the rules and data points (Xij = 1 means the jth rule is satisfied by the ith data point )?

ruleI = sapply(ruleMetric[,"condition"],rule2Table,X,target)

.   see the usage in the selectRuleRRF.R function. https://github.com/cran/inTrees/blob/master/R/selectRuleRRF.R

Comment: btw, the two solutions above are essentially the same. The idea is to calculate a matrix indicating whether a data point satisfies a rule. And this matrix would also indicate whether a rule can be applied to a data point.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me posted. I have the solution.

Comment: Your 1st comment helped a lot in identifying the rule being satisfied.